# How to copy images without losing their size?

Tags: canon, raw, jpeg

For a project it has been specified that my images need to be at least 6MB. However, whenever I copy or move them around they dramatically decrease in size - and that is even before I have edited them which compresses them further.

I have tried shooting in JPEG and RAW+JPEG but they still go very small when I want to move them off my camera memory card.

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: What method are you using to "copy" files? Copying by definition should result in a byte-for-byte identical copy, meaning absolutely no change in size. If you're using some sort of application to "import" or "download" files instead of copying, then it's quite possible that application is doing something other than just plain copying...

Comment: To help you better, it would be great if you could give a few answers to the following questions:
- Which camera do you have?
- How do you move the pictures (from where to where)?
- Which operating system do you use?
- Which programs do you use?
Generally, RAW is better at taking photos and editing without loss.

Comment: 6MB is a meaningless criterion. if they specified it like that, it's not your fault, of course, but are you sure it isn't 6M**P** (6 megapixels)?

Answer (score 3):

> For a project it has been specified that my images need to be at least 6MB. However, whenever I copy or move them around they dramatically decrease in size - and that is even before I have edited them which compresses them further.

You've been given a poorly considered requirement. Most likely, the intent was to specify some sort of minimum resolution for your images, but some images compress more readily than others. Double check that the requirement really is for 6 *megabyte* images and not 6 *megapixel* images — it'd make much more sense to specify the file size in terms of pixels, since the pixel dimensions will remain the same regardless of compression. If they really did say *megabytes*, you might ask for some clarification about what they really mean, or what image dimensions they'd like.

> I have tried shooting in JPEG and RAW+JPEG but they still go very small when I want to move them off my camera memory card.

It sounds like you might not actually be importing the RAW version of the file, or you might be importing it but only looking at the JPEG image. JPEG files are generally a lot smaller than their RAW counterparts.

Comment: Just to tickle my mind on how certain images compresses easily, a plain white image at 16MP will compress down to 187KB, and when I use GIMP to introduce maximum RGB noise to the white image, at 16MP, that JPEG is 29MB.